# How to replace empty elements in 2D java arraylist?

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap, guava, opencsv

I'm intending to replace empty elements in `ArrayList` with leading/trailing element values if similar or NA. The program returns `false` in the initial step of running, so I cannot proceed to implement it. What am I doing wrong? Kindly suggest an appropriate approach for me, thanks

```
            File file=new File("file1.csv");
            Scanner inputStream;
            List<String> header = null; //Store the header in a separate list
            List<List<String>> lines = new ArrayList<>();
            try{
                inputStream = new Scanner(file);

                while(inputStream.hasNext()){
                    String line= inputStream.next();
                    String[] values = line.split(",");
                    if (header == null){
                        header= Arrays.asList(values);
                        continue;//go to the next line as header is read
                    }
                    // Adds the currently parsed line 
                    lines.add(Arrays.asList(values));
                }
                inputStream.close();
            }catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
             //fails; outputs "false"
               System.out.println(lines.removeAll(Arrays.asList(Arrays.asList(" "))));

              //test on 1D arraylist- successful
              List<String> colors = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("R", " ", "G", " ", "B"));
              colors.removeAll(Arrays.asList(" "));
              System.out.println(colors);   
// OTHER part of program ..., file2 is expected results
```

`file1`

```
ID  577 592 598 600 612 650 700 822 825 830 840 870
Line0   A           A                   A           A
Line1   B           B                   NA          B
Line2   B           A                   A           A
```

`file2`

```
ID  577 592 598 600 612 650 700 822 825 830 840 870
Line0   A   A   A   A   A   A   A   A   A   A   A   A
Line1   B   B   B   B   NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  B
Line2   B   NA  NA  A   A   A   A   A   A   A   A   A
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe the line `String[] values = line.split(",");` is wrong, I don't see any `,` in your input file

Comment: Thanks @ivan-uqido for your response.The actual file loaded is a csv file...just pasted tab delimited there for readability purposes.